# Boas práticas na utilização de conexões a BD via Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Quando definida a classe de contexto no Entity Framework (exemplo):

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Categoria> Categorias { get; set; }
}
```

E utilizada nas classes DAO ou nos Controllers:

```
private Context db = new Context();
```

Qual a melhor maneira de utilizar a referência a `Context`?
Seria mais performático se `db` fosse `static`? 
Há literatura pertinente a respeito dessa questão, relacionada a um ambiente com bastantes usuários concorrentes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`DbContext` **não** é uma classe *thread-safe*, então não deve ser usada como `static` (o que eu imagino que seja como um [singleton](/questions/tagged/singleton)). Os objetos anexados neste contexto também não são *thread-safe*, o que pode criar conflitos.

Isso faz com que a ideia de usar um contexto por `Controller` seja uma boa ideia, visto que ao destruir o `DbContext` de cada `Controller`, é chamado o método `Dispose` para cada `DbSet`, e consequentemente para cada objeto ligado a cada `DbSet`. Isto garante que quaisquer modificações pendentes sejam devidamente resolvidas na expiração do objeto.

Ainda assim, se for interessante usar um padrão [singleton](/questions/tagged/singleton) para o `DbContext` na sua aplicação, poderia ser necessário escrever uma lógica adicional nas classes para verificar se o objeto está anexado ao contexto ou não, travar determinadas partes do contexto (como cada `DbSet`, por exemplo) como regiões críticas, e assim por diante, mas não creio que isso seja uma boa ideia.

Comment: Obrigado, @Cigano! Pena que só posso escolher uma resposta, porque a sua foi muito boa também.

Comment: Sem problemas. O importante é contribuir ;)

Answer (score 5):

Geralmente o `DataContext` é instanciado em cada objeto (um CRUD de Usuários por exemplo, portanto Class Usuários).
Não é uma boa prática usá-lo como singleton nem estático [**ref 1**], ([sigleton != static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519520)). Aliás singletons devem ser minimizados numa aplicação [**ref 2**].

```
public class Usuarios
{
    private Context db = new Context();

    private Usuario getUser(int id){
        return (from x in db.Usuarios
                where x.UsuarioID == id && !x.Excluido
                select x);
    }

    private IEnumerable<Usuario> getUserList(){[..]}

    private bool SaveUser(Usuario info){[..]}
    [..]
}
```

Há quem instancie a cada método:

```
    private Usuario getUser(int id){
        var db = new Context();
        return (from x in db.Usuarios
                where x.UsuarioID == id && !x.Excluido
                select x);
    }
```

e há quem instancie em cada método desalocando com `using`:

```
    private Usuario getUser(int id){
        Usuario result = null;

        using (var db = new Context()){
            result = (from x in db.Usuarios
                where x.UsuarioID == id && !x.Excluido
                select x);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Porém, conforme [já discutido no SO-inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/a/389871/986862), na prática torna-se desnecessário desalocar a variável do Contexto após usá-la já que o Garbage Collector já cuida disso logo após perceber o fim do uso da variável de Contexto. Aliás por essa causa, não só desnecessária como um anti-padrão (*anti-pattern*) por sobreuso.

**Referências:**

**1**
http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2011/03/dont-use-singleton-datacontexts-entity.html
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735498
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735498

**2**
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020312
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86582/singleton-how-should-it-be-used?rq=1

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, completa e com bastante potencial ao aprimoramento. Já vou resolver o uso de `static` em alguns desses casos no meu app.

Answer (score 5):

A um bom tempo atras estudei e li muito sobre o uso do EntityFramework e cheguei a uma metodologia de programação, onde eu instancio o context em cada método, passado, se for preciso, o contexto por referência a outros métodos que chamo.
Procuro sempre usar a instrução using, garantindo assim que após a execução das instruções que necessitam do contexto o mesmo seja liberado de memória e liberando a conexão.
Não sei o quanto essa maneira de programar é eficiente, mas nas aplicações que já tenho, nunca tive problema com performance.

```
private Usuario getUser(int id)
{
    Usuario usuario = null;
    using (var db = new Context()) 
    {    
       usuario  = (from x in db.Usuarios
            where x.UsuarioID == id && !x.Excluido
            select x).FirstOrDefault();
    }
    //outras instruções que não necessitam de conexão com o banco

    return usuario;
}
```

Comment: Parece ainda não haver um consenso se deve-se deixar isso ao cargo do `GC` ou usar `using`. Em todo caso, muito obrigado por sua contribuição!

Answer (score 3):

Se você criar uma `context` para cada objeto, como no primeiro exemplo, você terá problema se os objetos são associados, exemplo: `Pessoa` e `Endereco`, onde `Endereco` aponta pra `Pessoa`. Assim, quando você tiver uma instância de `Pessoa` em uma `context` e uma instância de `Endereco` em outra `context` e precisar ligar esse `Endereco` à `Pessoa`, vai dar erro dizendo que não pode porque fazem parte de `contexts` diferentes.

Como no segundo exemplo, só é possível se você consegue resolver tudo em um só método. Horrível! Exemplo: eu posso ter um método que pesquisa pessoa pelo cpf.

```
Pessoa.pesquisaCpf(string cpf)
```

Neste método eu retorno uma pessoa e preciso fazer uma pesquisa utilizando uma `context`. Depois eu preciso criar um `Endereco`, usando o meu mesmo exemplo, e utilizo o construtor de Endereco, que vai criar outra context. Aí já vai dar erro.

Pra resolver tudo isso eu ainda estou usando somente uma `context` criada no login do sistema. Não estou contente com isso, porque as alterações feitas no sistema por um usuário não são vistas por outro usuário em outra máquina, até que o mesmo refaça o login. Isso estou tentando arrumar.